# Is it impossible to build an equiliteral square pyramid out of voxels?

Tags: python, math

My goal is to write a code in Python that builds a Sierpinski Pyramid out of voxels.

To start I tried building a normal pyramid out of voxels. I figured that the pyramid should be equiliteral so that the lateral edges have a 45° angle to the base, in this way they could easily be built with voxels touching each other only at the edges.

However, when trying to set the coordinates of the 4 base points and the apex point, I stumbled upon the following problem: the height of the pyramid has to be equal to the base edge multiplied by the square root of 2 and divided by 2. This means that the z-coordinate of the apex will always be a non-integer. The problem is that the x, y and z coordinate of each voxel has to be an integer. Does this mean, that it is impossible to construct an equiliteral square pyramid out of voxels?

Comment: *Does this mean, that it is impossible to construct an equiliteral square pyramid out of voxels?* Well, technically, yes, you might regard it as impossible to build such a pyramid out of rigid 1x1x1 cubes.  However, just like with Lego, you can build convincing approximations to non-integral-measured objects by using smaller cubes or by standing further away.  Sure, you can't build an object with a dimension of 1.41421... out of 1x1x1 cubes, but using 0.001x0.001x0.001 cubes you can come close(r).

Answer (score 1):

If you want your edges to be angled 45°, you don't need equilateral but isosceles edges.

But focusing on the 45° condition, this only means each time you move 1 direction in the x or y axis along the edge, you move 1 direction in the z axis, so it is in fact easy to do so : you can stack up squares of decreasing side length to construct your pyramid : e.g. put a 1x1 square on top of 3x3 on top of 5x5, and you have a nice pyramid with 45° angled edges.

Cross section :

```
  .
 ...
.....
```

Comment: I am going to try it out, thanks